# Best practice to remove array elements using as guide a master array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

this is the problematic:

I got a master array, it's an array that have all the entities in the game.

When an entity (unit, building, etc) dies, I remove that entity from the array.

Now, I got other several arrays that are "subgroups" from that array. Like, enemyEntities, alliedEntities, movingEntities, etc. Everytime I create a new entity I add it to the corresponding array.

Everything works ok, but, when I remove one element from the master array, I'd like to somehow automatically remove it from the other arrays, let say, in an elegant way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a remove-method which takes care of it all. Make it first remove it from the master array, and then from each sub arrays (if the object is found). A nicer way of doing it might be to put all arrays in a another array, and do that to each of them in a loop.

Comment: I see, I like that approach, I could use indexOf to find the element and iterate over all the arrays at once. Thanks.